# Same Album Art on All Tracks

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, media

I have an issue with WMP12 in Windows 10. One particular album cover shows up on ALL the tracks I have in my Music folder. I've searched the Net for solutions, tried them ALL, with no success. I know I can just use another music player, but, I do like WMP. Anyway, has anyone else had or has this issue? I spent all day yesterday trying to figure out how to correct this issue. Can anyone help, give me instructions to correct this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WMP saves album art as hidden JPG files in your music folder. First, make sure that Windows Explorer is set to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected operating system files. Then, navigate to your music folder. In that folder, look for JPG files containing the particular album cover that is shown on all tracks. Deleting these JPG files should get rid of the incorrect album art.

Especially JPG files named `Folder.jpg`, or whose filename contains a lot of zeroes, can cause this. It may also be necessary to look for album art JPGs in subfolders of your music folder.